# Query in Sql Server Update

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have two tables.

`Table A`:

```
name             empid     city
-----------------------------------
Joesph Morgan    JM2345    New york
```

`Table B`:

```
name 
--------------
Morgan, Joseph
```

Now I want to add a column in B which will contain the `empid`.

I could have joined the tables on the basis of name column but the difference in format is making it difficult for me.

I was at first altering the table B name as firstname lastname format and getting the data in the newly created column empid in B.

But I don't want to change the format of the data.

I took the following steps.

```
Alter Table B
Add Empid varchar(10)

Update table B
set name=CONCAT(REPLACE(SUBSTRING([name], CHARINDEX(',', [name]), LEN([name])), ',', ''),' ',LEFT([name], CHARINDEX(',', [name]) - 1)

Update table B
set empid=A.empid
where B.name=A.name
```

Please suggest me a way where the name column will remain as it is.

Comment: Fix your data. Add foreign keys and / or define the empid in one table and use it in the others instead of name. Otherwise you're just waiting for problems to occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..  [FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/51568/1)

```
create table A(
name varchar(50),
  empid varchar(50),
  city varchar(50)
)
insert into A values('Joesph Morgan', 'JM2345', 'New york')

create table B(
empid varchar(50),
 name varchar(50)
)
insert into B(name) values('Morgan,Joesph')
```

Updated Query ..

```
update B set B.empid=a.empid  from B, A where
A.name=(Substring(b.name, Charindex(',',b.name)+1,len(b.name)) +' '+
 Substring(b.name, 1,Charindex(',',b.name)-1)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your situation correctly, you want all current empID's  from your A-table in a new column in your B-table ?

```
ALTER TABLE  B
ADD empID varchar(10) NULL
```

So you created a new column in table B, that allows NULL (for now.)

```
INSERT INTO B (empid)
SELECT empid
from A
```

this will insert all values from A.empid in table B.empID

hope this helps